# UploadProgressChanged with Foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, webclient

Ok, I have this:

```
foreach (FileInfo fileinfo2 in Arquivos2)
{
    label8.Text = "Enviando(NFe): " + fileinfo2.Name + "...";
    label8.Update();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
    client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
    client.UploadFile(new Uri("ftp://" + ftp + "/" + caminho + "//nf//" + fileinfo2.Name), "STOR", @"C:\\NFe\" + fileinfo2.Name);
    bar++;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(bar);
}
```

Its work fine, but I have:

```
private void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBar2.Update();
}
```

and nothing happens with progressBar2...

How I can update my progressBar2 with a uploadprogress? I can't use UploadFile with UploadProgressChanged?

Comment: no one? :/ If I use uploadfileasync, its work, but I need use uploadfile...

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged.aspx

> This event is raised each time an asynchronous upload makes progress.

It is only raised by 3 asynchronous events. The version you are calling is a blocking method and does not return until it completes and does not raise progress events.